# Ubuntu 16.04 I uninstalled apache2 but can't reinstall it now

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I have a problem on an ubuntu 16.04 server that I set up. I suspected that I had made a number of errors when I installed and configured apache2 originally because it was not behaving the way it normally does.

I decided to uninstall apache2 completely, including removing the config files, so that I could do a "fresh" installation.

I ran these commands:-
service apache2 stop 
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
whereis apache2
rm -Rf /etc/apache2 /usr/lib/apache2 /usr/include/apache2

After the above, I did another whereis and decided to remove more stuff
rm -Rf /usr/sbin/apache2 /usr/share/apache2 /usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz

Then everything was gone!

I rebooted the server.

However, when I now say:
apt install apache2

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

But I checked and /etc/apache2, etc is gone. 
It is as if it is telling me apache2 is still there?

I'm confused! Help!

Answer (score 17):

Follow these steps to remove the `apache2` service using `Terminal`:

1. First stop the apache2 service if it is running with: `sudo service apache2 stop`
2. Now remove and cleanup all the apache2 packages with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
   //or 
   sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2-bin apache2.2-common
   ```
3. Finally, run `sudo apt-get autoremove` just in case any other cleanup in needed

You can do the following two tests to confirm apache has been removed:

1. `which apache2` - should return a blank line
2. `sudo service apache2 start` - should return `apache2: unrecognized service`

answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/176966/767495)

Comment: We should also run `whereis apache2` to determine if there is any apache2 folder left.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt remove apache2*`

This worked on Ubuntu 20

Answer (score -3):

Have you installed another server? If the another server path is the same apache server path(e.g /var/www/html/index.html), the server will display apache page. Thus check the another server path.